# How to list all function names of a Python module in C++?

Tags: python, c++, python-c-api

I have a C++ program, I want to import a Python module and list all function names in this module. How can I do it?

I used the following code to get the dict from a module:

```
PyDictObject* pDict = (PyDictObject*)PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
```

But how to list the functions names?

Comment: thanks for your reply , actually my requests is import a python module into C++ and get all function names and filled them to a combobox that i can select which function to be executed , and i am not familiar with python CAPI , so i don't know how to extract function names , i found PyModule_GetDict function but don't know how to iterate over it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Out of curiosity, I tried to puzzle this out.

First, a minimal Python module `testModule.py`:

```py
def main():
  print("in test.main()")

def funcTest():
  print("in test.funcTest()")
```

Second, a minimal C++ sample `testPyModule.cc` to load and evaluate the `testModule`:

```cpp
// standard C++ header:
#include <iostream>

// Python header:
#include <Python.h>

int main()
{
  // initialize Python interpreter
  Py_Initialize();
  // run script
  const char *const script =
    "# tweak sys path to make Python module of cwd locatable\n"
    "import sys\n"
    "sys.path.insert(0, \".\")\n";
  PyRun_SimpleString(script);
  // get module testModule
  PyObject *pModuleTest = PyImport_ImportModule("testModule"); // new reference
  // evaluate dictionary of testModule
  PyObject *const pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModuleTest); // borrowed
  // find functions
  std::cout << "Functions of testModule:\n";
  PyObject *pKey = nullptr, *pValue = nullptr;
  for (Py_ssize_t i = 0; PyDict_Next(pDict, &i, &pKey, &pValue);) {
    const char *key = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(pKey);
    if (PyFunction_Check(pValue)) {
      std::cout << "function '" << key << "'\n";
    }
  }
  Py_DECREF(pModuleTest);
  // finalize Python interpreter
  Py_Finalize();
}
```

Output:

```
Functions of testModule:
function 'main'
function 'funcTest'
```

**Notes:**

To puzzle this out, I had to dig through the doc. pages. These are the links for the pages I used:

- [Importing Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/import.html): `PyImport_ImportModule`
- [Module Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/module.html): `PyModule_GetDict()`
- [Function Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/function.html): `PyFunction_Check()`
- [Dictionary Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/dict.html): `PyDict_Next()`
- [Unicode Objects and Codecs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html): `PyUnicode_AsUTF8()`.

It's obvious that I didn't check any pointer for `NULL` (or `nullptr`) to keep the sample short and compact. Production code should do this, of course.

Comment: thanks very much , i learn much from your code , that's helpful , really appreciated

Comment: Even aside from error checking, this is highly non-idiomatic.  What happened to `PyImport_ImportModule` and `PyDict_Next`?

Comment: @DavisHerring May be, I didn't dig hard enough. I made and checked a revised sample according to your hints. Thanks for the comment.